# error with task in microc for pic

Tags: c, embedded, integer, type-conversion, microcontroller

```
char uart_rd;
int b;

void main() {
  ANSEL  = 0;    
  ANSELH = 0;
  C1ON_bit = 0;  
  C2ON_bit = 0;
  TRISC = 0;
  PORTC = 0x00;
  UART1_Init(9600);               
  Delay_ms(10);                  
  UART1_Write_Text("Start");          
  UART1_Write(10);             
  UART1_Write(13);

  while (1) {                     
    if (UART1_Data_Ready()) {     
      uart_rd = UART1_Read();     
      UART1_Write(uart_rd);       
      **WordtoInt(uart_rd, b)**- this line code is my error

       if(b <= 20)
       {
              PORTC = 0x01;
       }
       if(b > 20)&&(b <= 40)
       {
              PORTC = 0x03;
       }
       if(b > 40)&&(b <= 60)
       {
              PORTC = 0x07;
       }
       if(b > 60)&&(b <= 80)
       {
              PORTC = 0x0F;
       }
       if(b > 80)&&(b <= 100)
       {
              PORTC = 0x1F;
       }


    }
  }
}
```

This is my task. When I build it, it shows me an error.

I read numbers from `0 to 100`, which indicate the battery charge and depending on the charge, `0 to 5` pins of `port C` will glow.

Could someone help me, how to find function which convert word to int?

Answer (score 1):

uart_rd is a one byte char variable. b is in integer variable. To convert uart_rd to b just do this:

```
b = (int) uart_rd;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the unnecessary/implied `(int)` cast?

Comment: Just to prevent any compiler warning if warning level set to high.

Comment: There can be a warning here only if sizeof(int)=sizeof(char) and char is unsigned char. An unlikely combination.

Comment: I agree that doing the assignment without the type cast does the job, but to be on the safe side I always add the type cast regardless of the data types. Not all C compilers behave the same in terms of warnings on type cast.

Comment: Unless the condition is met, there's just nothing to warn about.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply `b = uart_rd;` or `b = (unsigned char)uart_rd;`?